# Is it reliable & consistent to use Scala ToolBox for Creating Akka FSMs Dynamically?

Tags: scala, akka, fsm, toolbox

I'm working on a rules project that involves FSMs(AKKA) to be created dynamically using input parameters defined by the user.
Unfortunately, I found weired exceptions by Toolbox while evaluating the tree and it is not giving me the consistent results. For the same code its builds the tree and evaluates and it is throwing the following exception some times, I'm little worried on what to debug. Please shed some light on the same if you ever encounter as of such.

Here is what I do:
 1.Get the code from external program source by the user
 2.Feed that code to a function that builds FSM and returns its ref.

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(value _1$mcI$sp, value _1$mcI$sp, value _1$mcI$sp, value _1$mcI$sp, value _1$mcI$sp, value _1$mcI$sp)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.suchThat(Symbols.scala:1916)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.matchingSymbolInPrefix$1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1460)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transformSelect$1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1483)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1579)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.reportError(SpecializeTypes.scala:1420)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1371)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1347)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)

Comment: Have you tried twitter's eval? Maybe it works better for you: https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala

Comment: hveiga, thanks for the response.   Surprisingly I 'm not seeing this issue on a remote box where I finally deploy! Do you think is it because of resources  & stuff.? I'm just guessing if it is a kind of timeout internally  within Scala Toolbox? Any thoughts?